# Laravel Mix + Vue: Separating js and css

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel project and I'm using single vue components where the template, script and css are in a single Vue component. 
I have my laravel mix options set to `extractVueStyles` so that when i run `npm run production`, i get a JS file and a CSS file.  I have the js file set to :
`mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')` so that the bundled JS file is put in a dist folder.
However, the outputted CSS file is placed in the `public/css/vueStyles.css" folder.  Should this be in dist folder for continuity with the JS?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's ok. I like that you worry about continuity though.